# Can you tell Java to make a new variable based on the input it recieves via java.util.scanner?

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

This is my first question on this site, and I'm new to Java.

I've been working on a Java program that asks you to input a number grade in the console, then asks you to put in another grade, then asks you if you want to add a new grade, and if you type "false" it takes the average of those two grades and tells you your letter grade, by converting the number grade into a letter grade.

If you type "true," on the other hand, it asks you to input another grade, and once you input it, it asks again if you want to add another grade, until you say false.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReportCard {//converts number grades to letter grades
    public char convertGrades( int testResult){
        char grade;
        if (testResult >= 90){
            grade = 'A';
        }else if (testResult >= 80 && testResult < 90){
            grade = 'B';
        }else if (testResult >= 70 && testResult < 80){
            grade = 'C';
        }else if (testResult >= 60 && testResult < 70){
            grade = 'D';
        }else {
            grade = 'F';
        }
        return grade;
        
    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    
    ReportCard rc = new ReportCard();
    
    System.out.println("Input your first grade number");
    
    int number1 = in.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Input your second grade number");
    
    int number2 = in.nextInt();
    
    char yourGrade = rc.convertGrades(number1);
    
    double averageGrade = (number1 + number2)/2;//calculates average number grade. This will have to be changed to add the number of times I want a new grade, and divide by this same number
    
    
    
    yourGrade = rc.convertGrades(number2);
    
    System.out.println("Add grade? (True/False)");
    
    boolean bn = in.nextBoolean();
    if (bn == true) {
        System.out.println("Input your next grade number");
        //This is where I'm stuck
        System.out.println("Add grade? (True/False)");
        }
    if (bn == false) {
            System.out.println("Your average grade is "+ averageGrade);
            System.out.println("Your final grade is " + rc.convertGrades((number1+number2)/2));
            }
    
}
}
```

Is there any way to tell Java to make a new number every time I input "true" in the console, and add this number to the averageGrade calculation?

Comment: Seems like you want a List of chars and you can add to that list each time

Comment: more like a `List` of `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linked list data structure. They are not fixed in size and can be dynamically added to. Your code might need to change a bit to read the last item in the list as the grade you want to check.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
//...
LinkedList<Integer> grades = new LinkedList<Integer>();
//...
if (bn == true){
    //..
    grades.add(in.nextInt);
}

// loop calculating average based on reading list
int avg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<grades.size();i++){
    avg = avg + grades.get(i);
}
avg = avg / grades.size();
```

Comment: @user15244370 upon revising the question again, I believe you are correct. Initially I had posted my answer but after seeing the first comment on the question, I thought I had misinterpreted the question and so added that section in

Comment: How exactly would I implement nextInt? Did you mean nextInt()? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Booper hi, apologies for the delay, hope that it is still relevant. But yes nextInt()